# Binding to custom built control according to different data

Tags: mvvm, windows-8, binding, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

Here's the issue, I build a special book reader/browser (For holy quran), my code behind loads the page and constructs how it should look. and then it should bind that look to a some kind of data-bindable custom control to view it properly. the problem is, the look differs from page to page, so I cannot bind to a certain control or wrap panel.

here's how it generally looks: 
[image]

The decorative border top of the page is always there at any page, it indicates the part and chapter the viewer is in.

If you're starting a new chapter it have additional image under that decorative border or anywhere in the page (there can be multiple chapters in the same page) something like this

[image]

or this:

[image]

The normal text is not an issue, it's just a special font, however, I put each individual word in its own text block for reasons of user selection by word.

The issue here is, given the previous information, and knowing how random it is to place the  decoration picture or the amount of words (text blocks) per page. how can I bind that to some kind of view to separate the view from the VM and Engine that builds the page.

my past solution was to actually build everything in the VM in a wrappanel built inside a scrollviewer having lots of textblocks and images according to the page. but that's naiive solution. I want to rebuild that in a more professional separated way. I also want to do this for Windows RT beside Windows phone so I need to reuse the code behind in a Portable class library.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is slightly adjust your current design.  So perhaps have a VM that represents the entire content, and that would have a Collection of say Pages or Sections.  A second VM would represent the Page/Section, allowing you to create a property for the WrapPanel content (i.e. the words) and another property for the Header and or other things.

In the View you would have the scrollviewer and bind to the main VM collection.  Then create another View or DataTemplate that represents the Page/Section.

You should be able to do this is a strict MVVM sense quite easily and it will be dynamic based on the content.

You could even cater for advanced scenarios where each section has a different template/view.